# An error occurred using the connection to database 'myDb' on server 'tcp:xx.xxx.xxx.xx'. SQL Server - Google Cloud

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-sql

I'm having a problem deploying my app. The error, below, says that there is an error connecting to the database.

Here is my connection string:

```
"Server=tcp:'sql server public IP';Database=MyDB;User Id=sqlserver;Password=passwd"
```

The strange thing is that, when I connect through my local computer, adding a firewall rule, everything is ok, but when trying to connect to the Google Cloud server, I get this error. If anyone can help me, I appreciate it.

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Application startup
> error! Code: APP_CONTAINER_CRASHED [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35] No
> XML encryptor configured. Key {59e7d5ed-be7f-4680-94d6-65c08cd5b7df}
> may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
>
> [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
>
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'MyDB' on server
> 'tcp:sql serve public IP'.
>
> [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
>
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for
> context type 'MyProject.Data.NoVolanteContext'.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could
> not open a connection to SQL Server) at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
> newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
> userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean
> applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool
> pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
> DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
> DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
> pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
> DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection) at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection) at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
> allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()

Comment: Did you also add a firewall rule to allow the web hosting server @ Google access to the SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. All App in the project are Authorized.

Comment: It would be good if you could add details of your application, such as framework, how exactly are you trying to connect to your database, etc, due to the fact that the error seems related to the way that you're deploying the application. Besides that, checking the official documentation, might help you [diagnosing issues](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues). In addition to that, please, take a look at this article [here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), so you can improve your question, so the Community can help you answering it.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I'm new here. I'm using Sql Server Express 2017, and my project is in asp.net core 3.1, with EntityFrameworkCore. When I run locally, it works normally and I can connect to the database remotely. When I deploy it gives this error.

Comment: I'm publishing using Google Cloud Tools in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation on [how to deploy ASP.net in Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-dotnet-applications)? There are some specific guidances and ways that you need to follow. And have you checked the [diagnosing issues](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues) documentation that I provided the link?